# Checkout merge request branch without adding remote

Tags: git, gitlab

I love the tool for GitHub called Hub, but I can't use it at work with my company's GitLab server. GitLab's solution is to provide these instructions when I want to check out a merge request branch for review:

> Step 1. Fetch and check out the branch for this merge request
>
> ```
> git fetch ssh://gitlab.myserver.com:29418/username/repo.git branch_name
> git checkout -b username/branch_name FETCH_HEAD
> ```

Which is fine for checking out the branch but not useful when there's updates that I want to fetch (I have to delete the branch and run this command again. What I really want is to have a command that will add it to my repository's `.git/config` like this:

```
[branch "branch_name"]
    remote = ssh://gitlab.myserver.com:29418/username/repo.git
    merge = refs/heads/branch_name
```

If I type that in manually, everything's great and I can `git pull` to my heart's content when there's an update, but I can't figure out the command to type in the first time to avoid having to go back and edit my `.git/config` manually.

And before you suggest it, yes I know I can add the `username/repo` remote, but there's a lot of folks on my team and I don't want to have all their branches cluttering up my local repo when I do something like:

```
git fetch --all --prune
git log --graph --all --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %Cred%cd %Cblue%an%C(auto)%d %Creset%s' --date=short
```

Comment: Interesting use case. I thought of to `git branch -u`, or even `git branch --set-upstream-to`, but they seem to expect a named remote you previously added. This scenario seems like a case for writing your own script...

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to be able to do a git alias, but it's looking to be a pretty complex alias at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution that uses the fact that GitLab mirrors the source branch of a PR into the target repo under `merge-requests/<number>/head`. This isn't my favorite solution because I've had issues in the past where the mirror was out of sync with the original branch for a long time, but it's all I've got for right now.

```
mr = "!f() { \
    git fetch $1 merge-requests/$2/head:mr-$1-$2 && \
    git checkout mr-$1-$2 && \
    git config --add branch.mr-$1-$2.remote $1 && \
    git config --add branch.mr-$1-$2.merge mr-$1-$2; \
    }; \
    f"
```

I'd still be interested to hear other solutions, particularly if it could work with the orginal source branch.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately your manual solution is adding two config values; you could do that with the `git config` command rather than editing the file directly.  I realize that's not quite what you meant, but it's probably an easier-to-script way of looking at what you're doing. (Especially given that you probably only have one remote URL; or, if not 1, few enough that you could create an alias for each if need be.)

The other way to look at this is, git's support for frequently accessing the repo at a given URL *is to add a remote*.  You've rejected this because it would include the remote tracking refs in the definition of `log`'s `--all` argument (and similar); but instead, you could reconsider what arguments you use.  For example if you added gitlab as a remote named `gitlab`, you could then

```
git log --exclude=refs/remotes/gitlab/* --all
```

or you might find that some combination of `--branches`, `--tags`, `--glob`, etc. might serve your needs better than using `--all` in the first place.

I would recommend considering those options, before spending too much effort trying to avoid using the remotes mechanism.

Comment: For your first point, I'm hoping to have something as simple as the alias that the GitLab folks suggest: `git mr <remote> <mr_number>`.

Comment: For your second point, my problem is that I review code from lots of folks on my team of ~15, so it's more remotes than would be trivial for aliasing. It would also make that `git log` command tricky (though not impossible, just very long).